# What a good date + time picker for jQuery (not jQuery UI!)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, picker

I need something like [this](http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input) , but with date picker.

I don't wanna include jQuery.UI only for date/time picker.
I was tried to search in google but found calendar that I need only for MooTools.

Comment: Please be more descriptive. IE: why does jQuery UI not suffice? What do you need from the date and timepicker? A basis Google search reveals plenty of options.

Comment: Tip: If you title is the same as your question, then your title is way too long, your question is way too short, or both. In your question you should specify what you are looking for in the component, i.e. what you mean by "good", and why a simple web search fails to answer your question.

Comment: You know that jQuery UI is a componentized download, right? You can just download `Core` and the `Datepicker` widget: http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified a jQuery calendar and added the time picker control to it some time ago. There might be better out there, but this has served our purposes just fine.

http://razum.si/jQuery-calendar/TimeCalendar.html

Answer (score 1):

see the following link,i think it may help you

- [Any+Time™ DatePicker/TimePicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/)